# Casting a Person object to string giving class cast exception

Tags: java

I have made a class of Person object which is implementing Serializable interface, which contains fname,lname,phone,address in its constructor, and i am storing the objects of this class in ".dat" file by streams, i wanna display these contacts on GUI so when i try to cast person to a string it gives ClassCastException, i will be thankful if someone will help.

this is a constructor:

```
public Person(String fName, String lName, String add, String ph) {
    //super();
    this.fName = fName;
    this.lName = lName;
    this.add = add;
    this.ph = ph;
}
```

and this is GUI class code:

```
public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {

    FileInputStream fis;
    ObjectInputStream ois;

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream("person.dat");
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        Person p = (Person) ois.readObject();
        String obj = (String) p.toString(); // giving error at this line
        StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(obj, " ");

        textField.setText(str.nextToken());
        textField_3.setText(str.nextToken());
        textArea.setText(str.nextToken());
        // System.out.println(p);
        ois.close();
        fis.close();
    } catch (Exception ee) {
        System.out.println("Cannot Read File" + ee.getMessage());
        ee.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you override `toString()`? Also, why are you casting *and* calling `toString()`?

Comment: toString() normaly returns a String object... you dont need to cast this. can you please post your toString method if you override it?

Comment: Which class name appears in the `ClassCastException`'s message?

Comment: `toString()` returns a String, and you should not be able to override it to return something else, so there's no way that statement is producing the exception.  (The cast is redundant but harmless.)  As Peter suggests, it's far more likely the error is coming from the case of the readObject() call.  I'm thinking the exception will tell you what's being cast to what, if you look.

Comment: I am calling toString() to cast person object to string and display it in GUI e.g FirstName : xxxx LastName:yyyy Phone: 3333 Address: P-8

Comment: Class Name : Cannot Read Filejava.lang.String cannot be cast to Person
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to Person

Comment: Like we said, the problem is on the prior line.  That's where the cast to Person is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is far more likely the ClassCastException is here

```
Person p = (Person) ois.readObject();
```

in this line the cast is redundant and you can remove it so it won't be happening here

```
String obj = (String) p.toString();
```

is the same as

```
String obj = p.toString();
```

However, if you don't have the latest copy of your code running it could be your program is not doing what this think it is doing.

Comment: @Asad I didn't think it would, which is why I didn't mention it in my answer.

Comment: Peter this is the first question i posted ever on stackoverflow so i answered to other posts in ur Section and sorry for confusing you. You helped me out and solved my problem thanks for that nice of you.